# number sequence in python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I make a sequence of numbers **-0.05 to 0.05** with **0.002** increment and store it in a vector?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

x=np.zeros(50)

for i in range(-0.05,0.05,0.002):
    x(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Numpy's [`arange()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(-0.05,0.05,0.002)
```

Which creates:

```
array([-5.00000000e-02, -4.80000000e-02, -4.60000000e-02, -4.40000000e-02,
       -4.20000000e-02, -4.00000000e-02, -3.80000000e-02, -3.60000000e-02,
       -3.40000000e-02, -3.20000000e-02, -3.00000000e-02, -2.80000000e-02,
       -2.60000000e-02, -2.40000000e-02, -2.20000000e-02, -2.00000000e-02,
       -1.80000000e-02, -1.60000000e-02, -1.40000000e-02, -1.20000000e-02,
       -1.00000000e-02, -8.00000000e-03, -6.00000000e-03, -4.00000000e-03,
       -2.00000000e-03,  4.16333634e-17,  2.00000000e-03,  4.00000000e-03,
        6.00000000e-03,  8.00000000e-03,  1.00000000e-02,  1.20000000e-02,
        1.40000000e-02,  1.60000000e-02,  1.80000000e-02,  2.00000000e-02,
        2.20000000e-02,  2.40000000e-02,  2.60000000e-02,  2.80000000e-02,
        3.00000000e-02,  3.20000000e-02,  3.40000000e-02,  3.60000000e-02,
        3.80000000e-02,  4.00000000e-02,  4.20000000e-02,  4.40000000e-02,
        4.60000000e-02,  4.80000000e-02])
```

You can pass this to `around` to round to a precision desired:

```
np.around(np.arange(-0.05,0.05,0.002), 3)
```

Which makes:

```
array([-0.05 , -0.048, -0.046, -0.044, -0.042, -0.04 , -0.038, -0.036,
       -0.034, -0.032, -0.03 , -0.028, -0.026, -0.024, -0.022, -0.02 ,
       -0.018, -0.016, -0.014, -0.012, -0.01 , -0.008, -0.006, -0.004,
       -0.002,  0.   ,  0.002,  0.004,  0.006,  0.008,  0.01 ,  0.012,
        0.014,  0.016,  0.018,  0.02 ,  0.022,  0.024,  0.026,  0.028,
        0.03 ,  0.032,  0.034,  0.036,  0.038,  0.04 ,  0.042,  0.044,
        0.046,  0.048])
```

Comment: Hi, My answer also includes an inclusive maximum which I think the OP was asking for. Maybe you would want to include this in your answer to.

Comment: Why do yo think that @PotSkill? I don't see any indication of this in the question — the code they posted: `range(-0.05,0.05,0.002)` would not include the max value. Most python functions don't.

Comment: The question states a sequence of numbers from -0.05 to 0.05 which I believe assumes an inclusive 0.05. Maybe I'm wrong though

Comment: Fair enough @PotSkill, maybe you're right— natural language can be vague.

Comment: Without clarification from the OP I guess we will never know. He accepted your answer so he must have been happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.arange()` like this:

```
np.arange(-0.05, 0.05, 0.002)
```

but it has precision problems around 0, as seen here:

```
array([-5.00000000e-02, -4.50000000e-02, -4.00000000e-02, -3.50000000e-02,
       -3.00000000e-02, -2.50000000e-02, -2.00000000e-02, -1.50000000e-02,
       -1.00000000e-02, -5.00000000e-03, -2.77555756e-17,  5.00000000e-03,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Another approach is to use integers and then divide after, like this:

```
np.arange(-50, 50, 2) / 1000
```

which produces:

```
array([-0.05 , -0.048, -0.046, -0.044, -0.042, -0.04 , -0.038, -0.036,
       -0.034, -0.032, -0.03 , -0.028, -0.026, -0.024, -0.022, -0.02 ,
       -0.018, -0.016, -0.014, -0.012, -0.01 , -0.008, -0.006, -0.004,
       -0.002,  0.   ,  0.002,  0.004,  0.006,  0.008,  0.01 ,  0.012,
        0.014,  0.016,  0.018,  0.02 ,  0.022,  0.024,  0.026,  0.028,
        0.03 ,  0.032,  0.034,  0.036,  0.038,  0.04 ,  0.042,  0.044,
        0.046,  0.048])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact very simple with NumPy.

Just use np.arange()

```py
import numpy as np

step = 0.002
mini = -0.05
maxi = 0.05

for i in np.arange(mini, maxi+step, step):
    print(round(i, 3))
```

***note
This also rounds it to 3 decimal places as other wise it prints with about 46 decimal places.

Comment: I fixed my answer